# Implement IEnumerable<T> in C# on linked list built from scratch

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have built a linked list in C# from scratch and have solid unit test coverage to make sure it works.

To easily compare linked lists with lots of values I'm "enumerating" the values by hand using the standard while CurrentNode.Next != null, advance technique and storing those values in a C# List or array.

I want to implement IEnumerable on my custom LinkedList class and not rely on getting the enumerator from a private backing collection.

Here's the code of my LinkedList class. I feel like I'm overlooking something simple because the enumerator should just be an object you obtain from the collection class that provides a starting point and a next method as far as I can tell. I just can't get it to work in a generic manner.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpLibrary.DataStructures.LinkedLists
{
    public class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public Node<T> First { get; private set; }
        public Node<T> Current { get; set; }

        public LinkedList(T initialValue)
        {
            First = new Node<T>(initialValue);
        }

        public void AddNodeToEnd(T value)
        {
            Node<T> last = GetLastNode();
            last.Next = new Node<T>(value);
        }

        public Node<T> GetLastNode()
        {
            Node<T> last = First;
            Node<T> current = First;
            while (current.Next != null)
            {
                last = current.Next;
                current = current.Next;
            }
            return current;
        }


        public void Reset()
        {
            Current = First;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, remove `Current` and `Reset()` from the parent class, they don't belong there.

Comment: @Groo thanks, I was mistakenly implementing those navigation methods on the linked list collection class instead of in the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have created a custom collection, you won't be able to just use an existing `IEnumerator` implementation. You'll need to create one:

```
public class LinkedListEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
   public LinkedListEnumerator(LinkedList<T> collection)
   {
   }
   ...
}
```

I'm passing the collection to be enumerated into the constructor. Other ways could work but that seemed the easiest way to get it there. Now your `IEnumerable<T>` implementation is:

```
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new LinkedListEnumerator<T>(this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new LinkedListEnumerator<T>(this);
    }
```

Actual `IEnumerator` implementation left as an exercise.

Comment: One question on the IDisposable interface IEnumerator contains, If I'm dealing with an in-memory data structure (like your typical linked list), there isn't anything to dispose?

Comment: @JoshR Nope, probably not

Answer (score 7):

To add to Bradley's answer, note that methods returning `IEnumerator<T>` also support the `yield` keyword:

```
public class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    ...

    // this will automagically create the 
    // appropriate class for you
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Node<T> current = First;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Value;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // this will invoke the public generic
        // version, so there is no recursion
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You should, however, remove `Current` and `Reset()` from the parent class, they don't belong there. And your `GetLastNode()` method has two duplicate variables, you can remove one of them.